# Maven: Clojure + Groovy (Griffon)

Tags: maven, clojure, dependency-management, griffon, multi-project

I have a project who's business logic is in Prolog (will be rewriting to Clojure) and I would like to make a gui in Griffon. These two should remain decoupled, separate modules.

IntelliJ Idea can make an ant script for building such a project, but dependency management is quite tricky. Is there a way to build such project using Maven?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try https://github.com/nbn/griffon-maven-plugin or https://github.com/griffon/gradle-griffon-plugin

Be advised that both plugins are not 100% fool-proof at the moment.